# wx Python Label Right Align

Tags: python, label, wxwidgets

I have a label that I want right aligned and the text to be right aligned.  But when my code runs through and the label updates it, the StaticText aligns to the left of a button object.  My code is below

```
hbox14 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
self.buttonRemove = wx.Button(self.panel,label='Remove')
self.buttonRemove.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.removeAccount) # Remove account from list
self.labelSecTic = wx.StaticText(self.panel,label='0.0',style=wx.TE_RIGHT|wx.EXPAND)
self.labelSecTic.SetForegroundColour('white')
self.labelSecTic.SetBackgroundColour('black')
hbox14.Add(self.buttonRemove,proportion=0)
hbox14.Add(self.labelSecTic,proportion=1,flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.TE_RIGHT|wx.EXPAND)
```

When the label is updated I call

```
self.gui.labelSecTic.SetLabel(str(self.diff))
```

Any suggestions on how to make the labelSecTic stay fixed to the right side of the panel?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a side note: the style `wx.TE_RIGHT` is for `wx.TextCtrl`, it probably does nothing with the static text. About your real issue, you should force layout of the `hbox14` sizer. Not sure what is the sizer/panel structure of your window, you should call `Layout` on some ancestor of `hbox14`, it might be `self.gui.panel` or even `self.gui` (don't know what `gui` is), so for example:

```
self.gui.labelSecTic.SetLabel(str(self.diff))
self.gui.Layout()
```

or

```
self.gui.labelSecTic.SetLabel(str(self.diff))
self.gui.panel.Layout()
```